# How to translate a "formal" definition of the distributive property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

I have seen sometimes a formal representation of the distributive property over an operator defined as follows:

> A function $f$ is said to distribute over the operator $\bigoplus$ if
> there is an operator $\bigotimes$ such that  $f(x\bigoplus y)=f(x)\bigotimes f(y)$

When we see a definition like this, how do we "translate" it to a more concrete example?
E.g. multiplication distributes through addition and hence:
$x\cdot (y + z) = x \cdot y + x \cdot z$
So in this case what is the $f$ what is the $\bigotimes$ and what is the $\bigoplus$?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Where did you see this definition?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(t):=x\cdot t$, $\oplus:=+$, $\otimes:=+$.

Then $f(y\oplus z)=f(y)\otimes f(z)$.

**Edit**

Although I have answered the question as set, I think that the definition given isn't quite the one I'd expect to see. It makes sense, but forces us to treat the $x$'s individually. To get something more uniform I would have preferred a definition like this:

> The function $\mu: (x,y)\mapsto \mu(x,y)$ is said to right-distribute over the binary $\alpha:(x,y)\mapsto\alpha(x,y) $ if there exists a  binary $\alpha':(x,y)\mapsto\alpha'(x,y) $ such that
> $$
> \mu(x,\alpha(y,z))=\alpha'(\mu(x,y),\mu(x,z)).
> $$

Then in the example we'd take multiplication for $\mu$, and addition for each of  $\alpha, \alpha'$.

Comment: Both are +. Where's the distributivity?

Comment: @ancientmathematician: I don't understand the answer. My question was specifically how it is translated into the distribution of multiplication over addition

Comment: @Jim in the definition you gave, $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ can be whatever operations you want. There's nothing in the definition that says they can't both be the addition operation on the real numbers, for example.

Comment: @littleO: Then what is $f$?

Comment: As @littleO has said. In words "Left multiplication by $x$ distributes over $+$ because there exists an operation (also $+$) such that left multiplying the sum of $y,z$ by $x$ equals the sum of the results of left-multiplying $y$ by $x$ and $z$ by $x$."

Comment: JIm, $f$ is as I said, left-multiplying by $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the $\exp$ function, and the ordinary addition and multiplication/. You have
$$\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\cdot\exp(y).$$

Comment: I was interested specifically in the distribution of multiplication over addition